# How to get Pepper Robot's state programmatically?

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

When operating, the robot can encounter a variety of error states, such as overheating:

http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/family/pepper_user_guide/voice_notifications_pep.html#notifications-pepper

How can I detect the presence of an error condition using the Python API, and read those codes to act on them accordingly?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't forget how to create a [mre] of your own attempt, or how to [edit] your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [ALDiagnosis](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/diagnosis/aldiagnosis.html) API, the [getPassiveDiagnosis()](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/diagnosis/aldiagnosis-api.html#ALDiagnosisProxy::getPassiveDiagnosis) method.

By the way - you refer to NAOqi 2.8, which is [only for NAO6](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/news/2.8/whatsnew2.8.html). The last version for Pepper (as far as I know) is [NAOqi 2.5](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/index_dev_guide.html) (or [QiSDK](https://www.softbankrobotics.com/emea/en/support/pepper-naoqi-2-9/), aka NAOqi 2.9, which is for Android-based Pepper control).

Answer (score 0):

For overheating specifically, see [`ALNotificationManager`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/notificationmanager/index.html).
[For Pepper, it corresponds to the code 720](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/family/pepper_user_guide/voice_notifications_pep.html#notifications-pepper).
Note that these notifications are punctual and disappear when read. Thus when the notification has disappeared, that does not mean that the problem has disappeared, nor vice versa.